# Syncing a github repository with a distant server

Tags: github

We are two developers working on a single project. We are going to use Github.

I wonder if it's possible to automatically sync the content of a github repository on a distant server without having to "pull" the repository on my distant server?

Cheers

Comment: https://git-scm.com/documentation I believe what you want is to push to the server. Please read through the attached docs specifically git on the server.

Comment: @mthomp I think he wants his code on Server to be in Sync with github without having to pull..

Comment: It seems I misunderstood the question, Off the top of my head I'm not aware of a method to auto fetch and merge. Although I can't really see why you would want to do this... merge errors etc This can probably point you in the right direction http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31175338/ubuntu-automatically-pull-from-github-repo